# nfctools UL--NDEF write example

Tags: nfc

Anyone having an example of writing ndef record to Mifare UL type2 tags? with library 
https://github.com/grundid/nfctools ? I've tried using it, but couldn't succeed(actually couldn't write it).

```
NfcAdapter nfcAdapter = new NfcAdapter();
nfcAdapter.registerTagListener(new Type2NfcTagListener(new NdefWriter()));
nfcAdapter.registerUnknownTagListerner(new LoggingUnknownTagListener());
nfcAdapter.setTerminal(TerminalUtils.getAvailableTerminal());
```

Actually it's so easy in using Mifare Classic tags, but this UL is so much different in its way of implementing.

Comment: Can you show us the code you have tried with and an indication of where you are having a problem?

Comment: @paulkayuk please have a look at this http://pastebin.com/AaWAg6EY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing proper terminal and custom NDEFWriter (txtRecordWriter()) to Type2NfcTagListener would do the trick and by using startListening() on nfcAdapter will start listening for tag.
Sample snippet included here.

```
NfcAdapter nfcAdapter = new NfcAdapter(TerminalUtils.getAvailableTerminal(), TerminalMode.INITIATOR);
    System.out.println("Terminal found, preparing ...");
    nfcAdapter.registerTagListener(new Type2NfcTagListener(new txtRecordWriter()));
    nfcAdapter.registerUnknownTagListerner(new LoggingUnknownTagListener());
    nfcAdapter.startListening();
```

Comment: Where is the TerminalUtils class located in the nfctools project? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @BrendonDugan check this [link](https://github.com/grundid/nfctools-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/org/nfctools/examples/TerminalUtils.java)